# Espera en Java: Error en el orden de ejecución

Tags: java

Estoy programando un juego "Memo-Test":

*Pares de piezas iguales mezcladas, puestas boca abajo, y turno a turno se dan vuelta dos piezas: si son iguales, se sacan (dejan boca arriba), si son diferentes, esperamos 1 segundo para que el jugador recuerde donde estan, y las volvemos a poner cara abajo.*

Lo programo para un trabajo de la universidad. En general las mecánicas de ordenación, mezcla, "click" y que las fichas se den vuelta, funcionan.

Iban bien hasta que tuve que implementar la espera de un segundo:

```
public void espera(int i) {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(i);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PRO2PracticaFinal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Al principio lo hice poniendo "TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1)" en el mismo metodo, donde pone "joc.espera(1)":

```
joc.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override 
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (!jugada) {
                mouse_x1 = e.getX() / 150;
                mouse_y1 = e.getY() / 150;
                id_1 = joc.getID(mouse_x1, mouse_y1);
                joc.click(mouse_x1, mouse_y1);
                jugada = true;
                joc.inicia(true);
            } else {
                mouse_x2 = e.getX() / 150;
                mouse_y2 = e.getY() / 150;
                id_2 = joc.getID(mouse_x2, mouse_y2);
                joc.click(mouse_x2, mouse_y2);
                jugada = false;
                joc.torn++;
                joc.imprimir_matriu();
                if (id_1 == id_2) {
                    joc.set_trobades(mouse_x1, mouse_y1, mouse_x2, mouse_y2);
                }
                joc.espera(1);
                joc.tapa_jugada();
            }
        }
    });
```

La idea es que el metodo click, gira la ficha (la pone cara arriba), y una vez cara arriba (y aumentado el turno, etc) se inicie la espera de 1 segundo y se tapen todas de nuevo.

- El problema está en lo siguiente:

La espera se inicia antes de que la ficha se ponga cara arriba, provocando que en los dos casos:

**Caso 1:** las dos fichas son iguales, al dar vuelta la primera no hay ningún problema; pero a dar vuelta la segunda, se hace click, empieza la espera, y luego gira la ficha, y llama al metodo que tapa todo menos las parejas encontradas (tapa_jugada). Debería ejecutar la espera después de girar la ficha.

**Caso 2:** las dos fichas son diferentes, al dar vuelta la primera no hay ningún problema. Al dar vuelta la segunda: se hace click, empieza la espera, y cuando termina la espera rápidamente pone cara arriba la ficha clickada (y sin ni darnos cuenta) ejecuta el metodo de tapar.

Por qué pasa esto? Por qué no se ejecuta en el orden del código?
He probado como he mencionado aqui, llamando a un metodo en la misma clase, e incluso llamando al metodo (haciendo lo mismo, la espera) en otra clase.

Comment: El código no se ejecuta de forma lineal debido a los eventos de tu juego. Al estar programando con eventos, java ejecuta un Hilo de ejecución distinto al Hilo original de tu programa para gestionar el evento de forma paralela. De esta forma, tu juego no se interrumpe con cada evento generado por los botones del ratón. Para mas información, investiga en este [blog](https://www.thoughtco.com/event-2034091) y este [articulo](https://www.cse.wustl.edu/~kjg/cs102/Notes/EventModel/).

Comment: Tal vez lo más conveniente sea que uses [SwingUtilities](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml) para mandar el proceso de pintado junto con la actualización en un hilo aparte.